# Creating a layer / map from a kml file into java application

Tags: java, eclipse, kml, layer, geotools

I want to create a map layer using KML with Geotools library on a Java application (Eclipse based). The reading of KML data from files is working, but creating a layer out of it is what I don't know how to do.

The problem (I am not sure) is maybe rendering the KML as map:

```
public void render(final Graphics2D g2d) {
        if (map != null) {
            if (log.isDebug() && Component.traceLevel == 1) {
                log.debug("KmlLayer(" + getName() + ").render()");
            }
            final GTRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
            Rectangle imageBounds = null;
            renderer.setMapContent(map);

            imageBounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, viewport.getWidth(), viewport.getHeight());

            Point mapPos = viewport.getMapPosition();
            Point endPos = viewport.getMapPosition();
            endPos.x += imageBounds.width;
            endPos.y += imageBounds.height;
            Projection proj = viewport.getProjection();
            Point2D p1 = proj.getLongitudeLatitude(mapPos, viewport.getZoom());
            Point2D p2 = proj.getLongitudeLatitude(endPos, viewport.getZoom());
            CoordinateReferenceSystem sourceCRS = DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84;

            CoordinateReferenceSystem destCRS = null;
            ReferencedEnvelope mapBounds = null;
            try {
                // This is the WKT (Well Known Text) Definition for the Mercator
                // Projection. Source: http://spatialreference.org/ref/
                // You need this definition because geotools does not include it
                destCRS = CRS.parseWKT("PROJCS[\"WGS 84 / World Mercator\",GEOGCS[\"GCS_WGS_1984\",DATUM[\"D_WGS_1984\"," +
                    "SPHEROID[\"WGS_1984\",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0],UNIT[\"Degree\",0.017453292519943295]]," +
                    "PROJECTION[\"Mercator\"],PARAMETER[\"central_meridian\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_easting\",0],PARAMETER[\"false_northing\",0]," + "UNIT[\"Meter\",1]]");

                // At this point the Envelope for the map is created. In the same
                // step it has to be transformed from WGS 84 to Mercator
                mapBounds = new ReferencedEnvelope(p1.getX(), p2.getX(), p1.getY(), p2.getY(), sourceCRS).transform(destCRS, true);
                renderer.paint(g2d, imageBounds, mapBounds);
            } catch (FactoryException e) {
                if (log.isDebug()) {
                    log.debug("KmlLayer(" + getName() + ").render(): FactoryException caught!", e);
                }
            }
```

Comment: @GhostCat: Not asking anyone else to write the code for me. Just some insight if someone can provide. If you want to see the code, simply ask for 'that specific thing'. This community is also not for negativity I believe.

Comment: Way better now. But hint: I wouldn't log an exception for with "debug only". When that part goes wrong, something is seriously broken. You should definitely "communicate" that problem to the caller somehow.

Comment: 1) Web Mercator is [epsg:3857](https://epsg.io/3857) 2) I can't see where you read in your KML, which is where I would create the layer, 3) why are you handling all this yourself. Why not use MapContext etc as in http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/map/style.html#displaying-a-shapefile